# Some micro-steps to improve tags (early 2017)

Tags: discussion, tag

**Update**: I'll retire this thread now, and start a clean one: [Some micro-steps to improve tags (mid 2017)](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3039/17163)

Here's a list of steps to improve tag quality; I'm planning on doing these in increments so as to not flood the home page, and I'm posting it here to keep track.  I don't think any of these would be controversial, but let me know if you disagree.

It's an attempt to get rid of some [broken windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory), making the site look professional and maintained:

> Consider a building with a few broken windows. If the windows are not repaired, the tendency is for vandals to break a few more windows. Eventually, they may even break into the building, and if it's unoccupied, perhaps become squatters or light fires inside.

## Thus far:

These are gone now: [non-married](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-married) [practices](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practices) [verification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verification) [validity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/validity) [location](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/location) [dates](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dates) [believer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/believer) [hypothetical](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hypothetical) [comparative-madahib](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-madahib) [reappearance](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reappearance) [savior](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/savior) [kissing-children](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kissing-children) [last-sermon](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/last-sermon) [miraculous-healing](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miraculous-healing) [prophet-character](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophet-character) [wrongdoing](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wrongdoing) [source](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source) [ring](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring) [right](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/right) [reason](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reason) [proof](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof) [evidence](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evidence) [exodus](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exodus) [enemy](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enemy) [burn](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burn) [untagged](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) [adam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adam) [homosexual](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homosexual) [changing-religion](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/changing-religion) [steal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steal) [swearing](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swearing) [breaking-promise](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breaking-promise) [birthday-celebration](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birthday-celebration) [profit](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profit) [mahdi](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahdi) [old-women](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-women) [newborn](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newborn) [jurisprudence](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jurisprudence) [investing](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/investing) [intercession](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intercession) [afterlife](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/afterlife) [face](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/face) [brother](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brother) [disobedience](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disobedience) [quran-hadith](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran-hadith) [ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruling) [political](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political) [ornaments](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ornaments) [charity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity)<sup>([meta thread](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1883/17163))</sup> [fashion-designing](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fashion-designing) [sajdah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sajdah) [prophet-life](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophet-life) [learning](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) [medicine](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine) [make-up](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/make-up)<sup>([meta thread](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1769))</sup> [aqeedah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aqeedah)<sup>([meta thread](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1901/17163))</sup> [musa](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/musa)[moses](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moses)<sup>([meta thread](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2928/17163))</sup> [haj](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haj) [nature](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nature) [calamity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calamity) [shayatin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shayatin) [dealings](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dealings) [advice-request](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice-request)<sup>([meta thread](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2946/17163))</sup> [shahadah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shahadah)<sup>([meta thread](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2938/17163))</sup> [interpretation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpretation) [clarification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clarification)<sup>([meta thread](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2925/17163))</sup> [vice](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vice) [meaning](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning)<sup>([meta thread](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2925/17163))</sup> [haram-halal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram-halal)<sup>([meta thread](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1844/17163))</sup>

These have been added: [smoking](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smoking) [human-body](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-body) [anger](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anger) [cosmetics](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cosmetics) [software](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) [wali](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wali) [jealousy](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jealousy)

These have been updated: [school](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school) [tawiz](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tawiz) [transgender](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transgender) [evolution](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evolution) [baptism](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baptism)

## To do:

**Meta tags:** [islam-for-beginners](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islam-for-beginners) [difference](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference).  See Jeff Atwood, [The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), StackOverflow Blog, 2010 and the meta.SE question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283907/351283).

See meta threads: [Can we kill off the tags "clarification", "meaning", "islam-for-beginners", and "advice-request"?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2925/17163) and [Burninate request for the "islam-for-beginners" tag](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3005/17163)

**Tags to add:** [justice](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/justice) ([search](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=justice+is%3Aquestion)) [rajm](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rajm) (search: [stoning](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20stoning), [rajm](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20rajm)) [lying](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lying) (search: [lying](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=lying%20is%3Aquestion), [lie](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=lie%20is%3Aquestion)) [behavior](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) (search: [why do muslims](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=why%20do%20muslims%20is%3Aquestion))

**Tags to rename**:

- [mehr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mehr) (5) should be renamed [mahr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mahr) (0). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahr).
- [eid-ul-adha](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eid-ul-adha) (13) should be renamed [eid-al-adha](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eid-al-adha) (0). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eid_al-Adha).

## To think about:

- [reciting](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reciting): [1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1431/17163) [2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1431/17163) [3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1431/17163) [4](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38/17163), [reading-quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reading-quran) (18), [quran-recitation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran-recitation) (54), [tajweed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tajweed) (12).
- [polygamy](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polygamy) (10) should be renamed [polygyny](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polygyny) (maybe...).  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygyny).
- Replace [unbeliever](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unbeliever) by [non-muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-muslim): [1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37492/17163) [2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36247/17163) [3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30023/17163) [4](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29099/17163) [5](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24740/17163) [6](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11058/17163) [7](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5485/17163) [8](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/512/17163).
- Replace [kuffar](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kuffar) by [non-muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-muslim): [1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30668/17163) [2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/21401/17163) [3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/18850/17163) [4](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17971/17163) [5](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/14791/17163) [6](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10878/17163) [7](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10078/17163) [8](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7081/17163) [9](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7023/17163) [10](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7012/17163) [11](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5594/17163).

  Meta thread created: [What's the best way to reorganize the "kufr", "kuffar", "non-muslim" and "unbeliever" tags?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2985/17163)
- What to do about [work](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work) (56), [profession](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profession) (12), and [business](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business) (53).
- Get rid of [freedom-of-belief](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freedom-of-belief) (6).
- What to do about [birth-control](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birth-control) (1) and [family-planning](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/family-planning) (1) and [contraception](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contraception)?  Meta thread: [What to do about the "birth-control", "family-planning" and "contraception" tags?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2972/17163)
- What to do with [verses](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verses) (16), [quran-ayat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quran-ayat) (9), and [ayah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ayah) (7)?
- What to do about [drawing](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawing) (17), [image](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image) (31), [depiction](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/depiction) (3), [photos](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos) (10), [symbolism](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolism) (8)?
- What to do about  [sajda](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sajda) (14), [prostration](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prostration) (6), [sujud](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sujud) (3)?  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sujud).
- Are [terminology](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) (32) and [definitions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definitions) (22) synonyms?  And what about [meaning](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) (33) and [phrase](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase) (5)?
- Replace [adultery](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adultery) (9) with [zina](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zina) (46).
- [islamic-countries](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-countries) (5) should probably be renamed [muslim-countries](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muslim-countries) (0) to match [non-muslim-countries](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-muslim-countries) (25).
- Are [arabic](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arabic) (149) with [arabic-translation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arabic-translation) (26) synonyms?  Meta thread: [Should "arabic-translation" be a synonym of "arabic"?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2986/17163)
- Are [names](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names) (26) and [naming](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) (45) synonyms?

**Tag triangle**:

- [eid](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eid) (30), [eid-ul-adha](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eid-ul-adha) (13), and [eid-al-fitr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eid-al-fitr) (0).

It seems I'm not the first to do this:

- [Removing some tags](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/removing-some-tags?rq=1)
- [List of tag synonyms and tags to be burninated or removed](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149/list-of-tag-synonyms-and-tags-to-be-burninated-or-removed?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Do we really need a tag for "islamic scholar" I mean usually when we say scholar we mean a Muslim scholar? If so than scholar could be used as a tag for non-Muslim scholars!

Comment: Indeed "scholar" would be fine in the context of this site.  It doesn't strike me as particularly important one way or the other though, and there were more "islamic-scholar" tags used.

Comment: I see more islamic-scholar means more corrections! And now reading my suggestion of keeping scholar for non-Muslims, that would create confusion :S If islamic-scholar is more used we'd better stick on it even if it is somewhat too long!

Comment: How about [tag:caliph] and [tag:khilafah]? Seems like one should be a synonym of the other.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude: Looks right, but my knowledge of those terms is too limited, so it'd be better for someone else to sort that out.  Would it be possible to make a separate meta thread?

Comment: Certainly. I'll try to do so sometime in the next couple days. Thanks for all your efforts at improving this community by the way. I'm extremely impressed.