# Can we kill off the tags "clarification", "meaning", "islam-for-beginners", and "advice-request"?

Tags: discussion, tag

Can we kill off the following tags?

- [clarification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clarification) (28 Q's)  **Gone.**

  Googling [`site:stackexchange.com "clarification tag"`](https://www.google.com.au/?q=site:stackexchange.com%20%22clarification%20tag%22) yields no StackExchange sites where this tag has been beneficial.  It appears to be a tag used for questions whose author thought of the word "clarification" at the time of writing.  It the word is needed, it can be in the title or body of the question.
- [meaning](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) (33 Q's)  **Gone.**

  We should be careful with this one.  This might be best merged with [definitions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definitions) (24 Q's) or [terminology](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) (36 Q's) or [interpretation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpretation) (2 Q's).  Sometimes this is used to mean "symbolism".  **Gone.**
- [islam-for-beginners](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islam-for-beginners) (29 Q's; sorry Ahmed)  **Gone.**

  *Meta-tags, like [beginner]... are useless by themselves* -- [The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)
- [advice-request](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice-request) (18 Q's)  **Gone.**

  "advice" tag zapped on Stack Overflow ([meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64708/351283)): *It must be a contender for the most useless tag ever.*

These are [meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/):

> The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question. They describe some other aspect of the question, like the author’s skill level, or the author’s motivation for asking it, or generally what “kind” of question it is (poll, how-to, etc.).

Virtually any question can use any of these tags arbitrarily.  I don't believe they achieve a meaningful role in indexing the questions.  To illustrate, here's five random questions chosen using [DiceStack](https://www.isimonbrown.co.uk/dicestack):

1. [How is free will justified with those who are raised in a bad environment?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24103/17163)
2. [Is it allowed to sacrifice one day after Eid-ul-Adha?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9778/17163)
3. [Does a woman have to travel to where her husband live for the divorce to happen?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10675/17163)
4. [Where is Paradise and Hell?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12712/17163)
5. [Is backbiting from an anonymous online account still backbiting?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35171/17163)

Any of these four tags could be applied to any of these questions (almost...).  They have no real discriminatory power.

I was planning on asking later, but Ahmad Afif Khan is currently editing, so I wanted to propose this before too much takes place.

*Update*: [status-completed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed); all four of these tags are gone now.

Comment: +1 for "clarification", its very vague and generic ... almost every question will fall into it. Seems less relevant than a "baby" :p The purpose of a tag is to make stuff more easily searchable.

Comment: If we define them accordingly, then we may find them useful and can draw a line of distinction. Except [tag:advice-request] all the others may prevail **if you define them accordingly**.

Comment: I always found islam-for-beginners very vague as related questions had IMHO different levels. For clarification or meaning if they are used beside tafsir or hadith interpretation i would kill them else this should be verified. Don't touch the advice-request tag i've added it to several posts ;)

Answer (score 1):

[advice-request](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice-request) is now burninated.

[image]

See: [What does it mean to "burninate" a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/351283) at meta.StackExchange.com:

> A tag, when it's burninated, is removed from all questions that carry this tag. This will just remove the tag from the system, but it can easily be re-created by users with the privilege to.

I don't see much point in blacklisting it; an attentive community would be able to keep it at bay.

Answer (score 1):

[clarification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clarification) is now burninated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[meaning](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) is now burninated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[islam-for-beginners](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islam-for-beginners) is now (manually) burninated.

[image]

It got its own meta post: [Burninate request for the "islam-for-beginners" tag](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3005/17163)