# Burninate request for the "islam-for-beginners" tag

Tags: feature-request, burninate-request

I listed the tag [islam-for-beginners](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islam-for-beginners) in this question [Can we kill off the tags "clarification", "meaning", "islam-for-beginners", and "advice-request"?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2925/17163).

> *Meta-tags, like [beginner]... are useless by themselves* -- [The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

The 26 questions with this tag seem adequately tagged without the [islam-for-beginners](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islam-for-beginners) tag.  (In fact, many of the questions using this tag are by the user Ahmed (sorry Ahmed), who has written a series of good questions with this tag.)

So I'm requesting that the [islam-for-beginners](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islam-for-beginners) tag be burninated.

*Update*: [status-completed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed); this tag has been burninated.

Answer (score 1):

[islam-for-beginners](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islam-for-beginners) is now (manually) burninated.

[image]