# Tags "moses" and "musa" synonyms of "prophet-musa"?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag

I don't expect this will be remotely controversial, so I won't bother making this post too polished.

Can we make [moses](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moses) (6) [musa](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/musa) (3) synonyms of [prophet-musa](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophet-musa) (0)?

This is to match [prophet-adam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophet-adam), [prophet-muhammad](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophet-muhammad), [prophet-nuh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophet-nuh), [prophet-isa](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophet-isa) etc.

Comment: Yeah i think it would be better

Comment: For the sake of consequence do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done and done. [moses](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moses)→[prophet-musa](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophet-musa) and [musa](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/musa)→[prophet-musa](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophet-musa) have both been merged and synonymed.