# What to do about the "birth-control", "family-planning" and "contraception" tags?

Tags: discussion, tag

There's these three tags:

1. [birth-control](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birth-control) and
2. [family-planning](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/family-planning) (1 question)

   Both used for: [Family planning: Is it right in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36837/17163) tagged [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia) [family](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/family) [birth-control](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birth-control) [family-planning](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/family-planning)
3. [contraception](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contraception) (1 question)

   [What does Islam say about the right of the wife to have a child?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39169/17163) tagged [sex](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) [husband-wife](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/husband-wife) [pregnancy](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pregnancy) [contraception](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contraception)

### What should we do about these tags?

**Related questions**

Contraception:

- [Is it permissible to use contraception during intercourse?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38380/17163) tagged [sex](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex)
- [Is it halal to use condom?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7846/17163) tagged [women](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/women) [sex](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex) [adab](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adab) [sin-or-not](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin-or-not) [men](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/men)

Abortion:

- [Is abortion permitted in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/927/17163) tagged [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) [women](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/women)
- [Is abortion allowed for a woman / girl who is raped?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/28808/17163) tagged [islamic-philosophy](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-philosophy) [reference-request](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) [life](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life) [morality](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morality) [ethics](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics)
- [I want to ask God for forgiveness for an abortion](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35352/17163) tagged [sin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin)
- [I'm 5 weeks pregnant from unlawful relationship, should I abort ?!](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16186/17163) tagged [halal-haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halal-haram) [sex](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sex)

Virgin:

- [Wali's right to marry off a virgin without her consent in different madhahib](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39155/17163) [nikah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nikah) [fiqh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiqh) [wali](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wali) [virgin](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virgin)

Pregnancy: [pregnancy](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pregnancy) with 14 questions.