# What's the best way to reorganize the "kufr", "kuffar", "non-muslim" and "unbeliever" tags?

Tags: discussion, tag

These tags are closely related:

- [unbeliever](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unbeliever) (<strike>9 Q's</strike> now 0 Q's)
- [non-muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-muslim) (138 Q's)

  > This tag is for questions about Islamic guidelines for relations with people who are not Muslim.
- [kuffar](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kuffar) (12 Q's)  Should be renamed [kafir](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kafir) to match [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kafir).  I've heard this is considered pejorative (which would be justification to avoid this tag).
- [kufr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kufr) (31 Q's)

There seems to be some unused possibilities too [infidels](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infidels) and [disbelievers](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disbelievers).

**Question**: What's the best way to (re)oranize them?

This requires more Arabic knowledge and familiarity with these terms than I have.  I'm particularly interested in if "kafir" and "non-muslim" are the same thing.

Comment: Kafir and kufr are pretty clear central terms, and every Non-Muslim ("Muslim" read in the Abraham-was-a-Muslim sense) is a kafir. I see the fact that they are also used pejoratively by many Muslims as an outflow of Islamic doctrine; Islamic scholars agree they deserve eternal torture and are committing the worst crime, of course that's gonna be looked at in a bad light. I would keep kufr as its own tag since it refers to the sin, and merge the other three into kafir since that's the Islamic term.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is to

- keep [non-muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-muslim), and
- merge [disbeliever](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disbeliever) and [unbeliever](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unbeliever) as synonyms.

I am not too keen on the use of [kafir](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kafir). Most of the questions tagged with [kuffar](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kuffar) seem to be related to non-Muslims in general. The original meaning of the word kafir (to hide) remains to be the standard linguistic definition. The most commonly understood meaning from a religion's point of view is a disbeliever in Islam, as this also being the most use of the word in the Qur'an, but it is not the only use neither in practice nor in the Qur'an. It is used to refer to [farmers who hide seeds in the soil](http://quran.com/57/20/), or to [Muslims who disbelieve in man-made laws](https://quran.com/2/256/), or to refer to [Muslims who embrace walā' and barā'](https://quran.com/60/4/).

Comment: I agree that the word kafir shouldn't be attached to disbeliever or unbeliever or non-muslim, because of the possibility of the word kafir to mean something else, as some scholars actually do.. Do you also follow that opinion as is explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6wiYXrSWX8)?

Comment: @Kilise — Not 100% on all points. No one is always right, or always wrong, but in general I give more weight to *al-tafsir bi al-ma'thour* over *al-tafsir bi al-ra'y*, and to earlier generations of scholars. This is not to say that I automatically oppose either school or declare them wrong or .... It is just my own preference of what I feel more comfortable of following, based on discussions with followers of either school. In the end, all established scholars earned their knowledge and deserve all respect.