# Should "arabic-translation" be a synonym of "arabic"?

Tags: discussion, tag

We currently have two tags:

- [arabic](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arabic) (<s>150</s> 154 Q's)
- [arabic-translation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arabic-translation) (<s>28</s> 32 Q's)

**Question**: Should "arabic-translation" be a synonym of "arabic"?

I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be a synonym.  But it'd be nice to get some feedback on this.

The 28 questions with [arabic-translation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arabic-translation) are:

1. [What does "offer reals" mean in this hadith?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5532/17163)
2. [As per Qur'an 3:28, to what extent can Muslims receive help from non-Muslims?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8098/17163)
3. [What is 'wala' of a slave?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/14756/17163)
4. [Why Allah send darood on Prophet Muhammad(saw)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16268/17163)
5. [Can anyone translate these pictures for me?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/18820/17163)
6. [What is the Arabic word for "Demon" and "Angel"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/20105/17163)
7. [What is the meaning of this Arabic tawiz?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/21412/17163)
8. [What's the difference between the word "al-bahra" and "al-yammi" in the Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23161/17163)
9. [Muhammad, Mohammad, Muhammed, Mohammed, Mohamed, or Mohumed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23709/17163)
10. [What is the meaning of Bimashobih in surah 67:5](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24290/17163)
11. [How is Qur'an 13:15 justified?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24563/17163)
12. [What is the meaning of سعدیک and و الشرّ لیس الیک in this prayer of Istiftah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/25644/17163)
13. [Why is "وليتلطف" in Surah Kahaf is written in bold text in Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/25932/17163)
14. [What does “Inni Ka Lillah” and "Inni Qalillah" mean?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/26199/17163)
15. https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/28223/17163
16. [What does اذل and اعز mean in Qur'an 5:54?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29492/17163)
17. [What does the attribute of Allah "shafiul mudhnibin" mean?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/32762/17163)
18. [Meaning of the word "zafeer" in quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/32992/17163)
19. [Why are some muslims mistranslating Surah Hajj, Ayah 52?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33698/17163)
20. [What does this mean in English: "tafsirbi’l-ma’thur"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35173/17163)
21. [Does Qur'an 5:41 mean that all Jews "listen eagerly to lies", or that among the Jews there are some who "listen eagerly to lies"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35735/17163)
22. [What is the meaning of the word مريب in Surah qaf, Ayah 25?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36118/17163)
23. [What is the meaning of this taweez (tawiz) writtings?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36699/17163)
24. [How do the words monasteries, churches and synagogues occur in the Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38328/17163)
25. [Does "nikah" mean "sex"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38754/17163)
26. [What is the exact meaning of "soorah" (image in Arabic) in the ahadith which state "Allah created Adam in his image"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39132/17163)
27. [What does the exception in "No man should be alone with a woman except when there is a Mahram with her" mean?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39150/17163)
28. https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39358/17163

Comment: That's quite a long list and the first post on the list already makes it hard to take a decision! Especially as the English translator has done some ijtihad by maybe translating based on a commentary as the Arabic wording of the hadith doesn't directly imply the English content!

Comment: 2. is no more tagged arabic-translation, after your edition yesterday!

Comment: I didn't update the list since I first posted it (: