# Let's make "charity" a synonym of "sadaqah"?

Tags: feature-request, tag

Currently, we have a "tag triangle": [charity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity) [sadaqah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sadaqah) [zakat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zakat).  This was raised in 2012 here: [List of tag synonyms and tags to be burninated or removed](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/149/17163)

In this situation, we have:

1. Questions pertaining to "sadaqah" which don't pertain to "zakat".  E.g. [Should we give money to street beggar?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37611)
2. Questions pertaining to "zakat" which don't pertain to "sadaqah".  E.g. [Can someone give zakat to his unmarried (and young) brother?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37753)
3. Every question pertaining to either "sadaqah" or "zakat" also pertains to "charity".
4. The Arabic "sadaqah" and "zakat" are more specific and technical, in keeping with:

   > Using the proper vernacular is an important part of setting the right tone for the site. Certainly, questions involving simpler concepts are welcome, but you should not be targeting and reaching out to "curious onlookers" specifically. -- [Robert Cartaino](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/94) ♦

This leads me to propose: **let's get rid of the [charity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity) tag**.

Ordinarily, questions which pertain to "charity" can be instead tagged "sadaqah" and/or "zakat".  While it seems plausible that a question may pertain to "charity" without pertaining to "sadaqah" nor "zakat", it seems unlikely (and we have to trade it off with the alternative, i.e., retaining the tag triangle).

How to get rid of it?  **Making [charity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity) a synonym of [sadaqah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sadaqah) looks feasible.**

There are <strike>14</strike> 12 questions currently tagged [charity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity).  Of these:

- [Four](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity+sadaqah) are tagged both [charity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity) and [sadaqah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sadaqah), which will end up tagged only [sadaqah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sadaqah): [1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30594/17163) [2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/25646/17163) [3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/21712/17163) [4](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2015/17163).  This seems unproblematic.
- [Two](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity+zakat) are tagged both [charity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity) and [zakat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zakat): [1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37243/17163) [2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30383/17163).  I downvoted them, and they <strike>should be shortly</strike> were [automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year) (`RemoveDeadQuestions`).

  (This is ignoring the [two](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity+zakat+sadaqah) which also have the [sadaqah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sadaqah) tag: [1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/25646/17163) [2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/21712/17163), which are listed in the above bullet point.)
- In my opinion, the remaining eight seem adequately re-tagged [sadaqah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sadaqah): [1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17796/17163) [2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12323/17163) [3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11777/17163) [4](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10196/17163) [5](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9094/17163) [6](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33620/17163) [7](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/27870/17163) [8](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24609/17163).

(An alternative would be to use "charity" and get rid of "sadaqah" and "zakat", but points 1. and 2. above suggest this distinction is useful.)

Comment: I'd like to help, but as it seems i haven't answered any of these questions and don't have any positive score in these tags :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked through the listed questions and it does appear that the [charity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity) questions currently posted would work just as well (if not better) with [sadaqah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sadaqah); since there's been no apparent opposition to this suggestion for over a week since posting, I've gone ahead and merged/synonymed [charity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity)→[sadaqah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sadaqah).

Answer (score 1):

The reason put forward (is a well researched one) to merge [sadaqah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sadaqah) and [charity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity) is quite convincing. And these two should be converged... keeping in mind that,

- many users **are not** familiar with these Arabic terms.
- and they might find it hard to link their question to a suitable tag
  (especially non muslims).
- statistics show that people are using this tag:[charity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity)

That's why I think these two should be merged in such a way that if someone types `Charity` he would find `Sadaqah` in his suggestions.